# Rails signup with multiple ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On My current app that i'm developing, i can sign up using Facebook and Google+. But when I added the ability for signing up with just a regular email, i got this error, I'll appreciate some help please ...

Here are some of my code

```
#SessionsController    
   def create
     @user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
     # session[:user_id] = @user.id
     # redirect_to root_path
     @user = User.find_by_email params[:email]
     if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
       session[:user_id] = @user.id
       redirect_to root_path
     else
       flash[:alert] = "Wrong email or password"
       render :new
     end
   end



#user.rb
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do   |user|
    user.provider         = auth.provider
    user.uid              = auth.uid
    user.name             = auth.info.name
    user.email            = auth.info.email
    user.oauth_token      = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.image            = auth.info.image
    user.gender           = auth.extra.raw_info.gender
    user.location         = auth.extra.raw_info.location.name
    user.location          = auth.extra.raw_info.locale
    # user.url              = auth_hash['info']['urls'][user.provider.capitalize]
    user.save
  end
 end
```

So When attempting to signUp with using the email, here's what happen !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRpDh.png)

I'm guessing that error coming because i'm calling `from_omniauth` and i'm not passing a provider, which i don't need to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider starting fresh - using https://github.com/plataformatec/devise and then adding OmniAuth on top of this (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

Comment: Hi @BenHawker, thanks for the comment, But i'm trying to build all of the user authentication without using Devise ...